# distinction between post parameter and post verb in restful queries?

Tags: jquery, rest, post, get

I have a question that's been bugging me for a while, with restful applications you can do a `GET` request with a `POST` body as well as a `POST` request with `GET` headers. Is there a distinction between the verb `POST` and the parameter `POST`?

Also, in jQuery is there a way to add `POST` data to a `$.ajax({ type:'get' })` query?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as "GET parameters" and "POST parameters". They are only colloquially called so and that leads to confusion.

HTTP specifies several *verbs* for requests, which are basically the first thing in the HTTP request:

```
GET /foo/bar/baz
... further HTTP headers ...
```

The `GET` here could also be `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` or a number of less frequently used verbs. These don't have any specific meaning per se, but their use and desired behavior is specified.

URLs can contain *query parameters*, e.g.: `example.com/foo?bar=baz`. `?bar=baz` here are query parameters. These are colloquially incorrectly called "GET parameters".

The HTTP request may also contain *body data*. E.g.:

```
POST /foo/bar/baz
...

quix=42&farble=gorg
```

The last line here is the body data, colloquially incorrectly called "POST data".

Now, GET requests are not defined to allow body data. Technically you *can* send body data in GET requests, but it's specified as not allowed and any compliant server should ignore it. POST and PUT requests may contain body data. *Any* type of request may be for URLs which contain query parameters.

Hope that clears it up.

Comment: lolz ... someone should mention that to the developers of php since the parameters are accessed as $_GET['bar'] and $_POST['bar']. thanx for clearing it up

Comment: Yep... :( Very, very true... :(